# How to set foreign key where column names are different using Entity Framework 5 Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am trying to establish a foreign key relationship between following domain classes using Fluent API (Entity Framework v5):

```
public partial class User
{
    public long UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
public partial class AccountGroup : BaseEntity
{
    public long AccountGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
builder.Entity<User>().HasKey(p => p.UserID); //Set User Id as primary key
builder.Entity<AccountGroup>().HasKey(x => x.AccountGroupID); //SetAccountGroupId as PK
```

I am not sure how to set a relationship between User.UserId and AccountGroup.ModifiedBy column using fluent API. I can do this by Data Annotation but I am looking for a solution using fluent api

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. Are you trying to set ModifiedBy to be the FK for the User navigation property?

Comment: @TimB yes I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ModifiedBy property from your entity:

```
public partial class AccountGroup
{
    public long AccountGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And then map the foreign key like so:

```
builder.Entity<AccountGroup>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.User)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ModifiedBy"));
```

Use HasOptional instead if the foreign key should be nullable:

```
builder.Entity<AccountGroup>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.User)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ModifiedBy"));
```

You also don't need to specify the primary keys like you are. Entity Framework will discover those by convention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do understand that Entity Framework will automatically add the foreign key User_UserId column. However I would like to customise that behaviour by making AccountGroup.ModifiedBy as a foreign key to User.UserId column.

Comment: Updated my answer. I think it will do what you want now.